# Why can't we take the larger angle in Cross Product?

Tags: vectors, linear-algebra

Suppose, $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$ are inclined with each other at an angle of $\phi$. Then, their cross product would be defined as

$$\vec{A}\times\vec{B} = |A||B|\sin(\phi)\hat{n}$$

My Physics [textbooks](https://g.co/kgs/usfWMX) tells me to take $\phi$ as the smaller angle between the tails of $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$, i.e $0 \leq \phi\leq \pi$ to evaluate the cross product. To determine the direction of the cross product it tells to follow the right-hand thumb rule.

My question is that why can't we consider the other angle around the tails of $\vec{A}$ and $\vec{B}$, i.e the angle ($2\pi - \phi$) to evaluate the cross product.

Comment: We do this for the same reason we choose a right-hand rule rather than a left-hand rule: it’s just an arbitrary convention. Sometimes when defining things you have multiple options. You just pick one of them and stick with it for consistency.

Comment: That said… Doing it this way makes the *component* formula for the cross product have cyclic permutations of $x$, $y$, and $z$ components, which makes it easy to remember.

Answer (score 3):

Using the angle $2\pi - \phi$ would result in a vector pointing in the opposite direction as the standard cross product since $\sin(2\pi - \phi) = -\sin\phi.$ You could define another vector product to use this other angle like
$$A\bar\times B = |A||B|\sin(2\pi - \phi)\hat n = -A\times B,$$
but it would be difficult to use with other equations in physics since those equations assume the standard cross product is being used.

Comment: I have also checked by myself that taking the larger angle gives the opposite direction for the cross product.  But in the case of dot product, no matter which angle you are taking, the value is same for both the smaller and the larger angle.  Can't we make a cross product without the use of the right-hand thumb rule only by seeing the angle like we do in dot product?

Comment: @UttaranRakshit No. The reason is related to the fact that the cross product is antisymmetric, so $\mathbf A \times \mathbf B \neq \mathbf B \times \mathbf A$.  The reason that the dot product doesn't care about whether you use $\phi$ or $2\pi-\phi$ is related to the fact that $\mathbf A \cdot \mathbf B = \mathbf B \cdot \mathbf A$. You could try to define a different kind of vector product which is symmetric, of course, but it wouldn't have the properties that we like about the cross product (of which antisymmetry happens to be one).

Comment: @UttaranRakshit I don't know if I understand your question. Are you asking why we can't change the definition of the cross product to more closely align with the dot product? Or, are you asking for a more geometric definition that doesn't rely on an arbitrary right-hand rule? Or something else?

Comment: @MarkH I want a definition of cross product which is more aligned to that of dot product.  Can we define a symmetric cross product that will be equally valid for the angles ϕ and  (2π−ϕ) as it is in the case of dot product? Can we use this symmetric cross product in every area of Physics?

Comment: thank you, the best explanation I've heard

Answer (score 0):

In cross product of two vectors $\vec A$ and $\vec B$,

$\vec A \times \vec B=|A| |B|\sin \theta\tag*{}$
Here angle $\theta$ is taken as smallest angle between $\vec A$ and $\vec B$ because cross product gives area of parallelogram. It represent plane and magnitude of product is area of plane with two vectors, and direction is given by right hand rule or curl your fingers of right hand from first vector to second vector and thumb points to direction of cross product.

If magnitude of cross vector comes negative then it means angle measured in clockwise direction, that is not smaller one. In physical problem where order of cross product is defined as in torque, then it negative magnitude means opposite of supposed direction of cross product.

**Annexure**

About the non-symmetry of cross product,
$\vec A\times \vec B=-\vec B\times \vec A\ \text{but},\ \vec A\cdot \vec B=\vec B\cdot \vec A\tag*{}$ is due to unlike dot product which has $\cos$ of angle between two vectors that is symmetric, cross product has $\sin$ of angle which is not symmetric.